# Make the method parameterized

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer, parameterized-query

I have designed my application in a layered approach. I have a BusinessOP layer for each interface and a common data access layer. In my Data access layer I have Data Reader method like this.|

```
     public SqlDataReader executeQuerys(string query01)
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand com = null;
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(DBConnect.makeConnection());
            con.Open();
            com = new SqlCommand(query01, con);
            return com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }

        catch
        {
            com.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            throw;
        }
```

This is the code for my DBConnection layer.

```
     public static string makeConnection()
    {
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB.Properties.Settings.ConString"].ToString();
        return con;
    }
```

In my business layer I have methods like this each calling a specific stored procedure.

```
     public SqlDataReader getLGDivID(string divName)
    {
        string query = "EXEC getLGDivID'" + divName + "'";
        return new DataAccessLayer().executeQuerys(query);
    }
```

As my business operation layer is unsecure, I want to have it with parameterized query in here I'm using string concatenation to pass parameters. Can anyone hint me how to modify it?

Comment: Side note: You should always `.Dispose`, not only when you catch an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your function a little bit:

```
public SqlDataReader executeQuerys(string query01, string paramName, string value)
{
    SqlConnection con = null;
    SqlCommand com = null;
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(DBConnect.makeConnection());
        con.Open();
        com = new SqlCommand(query01, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, value);
        com.Dispose();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        com.Dispose();
        con.Close();
        throw;
    }
   return com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

then to use it:

```
public SqlDataReader getLGDivID(string divName)
{
    string query = "EXEC getLGDivID @divName";
    return new DataAccessLayer().executeQuerys(query, "@divName", divName);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

As `@silvermind` pointed out, you should dispose your connection properly.
The way you have it now it will dispose connection only when you catch an exception.

This is bad, make use of `IDisposable`, for example:

```
public SqlDataReader executeQuerys(string query01, string paramName, string value)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBConnect.makeConnection()))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            com = new SqlCommand(query01, con);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, value);
        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            //Handle the exceptio
            //no need to dispose connection manually
            //using statement will take care of that
        }
    }
    return com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

Comment: You could perhaps consider showing a proper disposal with a using block to improve the answer. :)

Comment: @meda it gives me this error, 
Error DataAccessLayer.executeQuerys(string, string, string)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: @chathwind it makes sense, check my edit, the latter function

Comment: @meda When I try to read the values in the data reader in the form code like this it
SqlDataReader reader = new CandidateOP().getLGDivID(cmbLgDiv.Text);
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        templgDivID = (Int32)reader[0];
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
It gives me the error Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed, but it worked with my previous code. What do you think the reason is..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62888/discussion-between-meda-and-chathwind).